"No boot device" after migrate VM from XenServer to Promox
XenServer 8.2
Promox 8.2.2
My VM OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
After I export vm from XenServer then import to Promox, I can not start VM. It said: "No boot device"
error image
here is my VM config on promox
boot: order=scsi0
cores: 4  
cpu: host  
ide2: none,media=cdrom  
memory: 4096  
meta: creation-qemu=8.1.5,ctime=1716453055  
name: Test.CpcApp  
net0: virtio=BC:24:11:AD:86:1F,bridge=vmbr0,firewall=1  
numa: 0  
onboot: 1  
ostype: l26  
scsi0: VM-Storage:vm-102-disk-0,iothread=1,size=36568M  
scsihw: virtio-scsi-single  
smbios1: uuid=bc91f0a5-b05c-49b4-8eb1-8a6b9bbf1c22  
sockets: 1  
vmgenid: 44a0c9d2-9523-4735-b1cb-51096192620b 

Here is my VM option on Promox
VM options
Please tell me why it happen ?
Thanks for your support.

How were you performing the actual "migration from Xen to PVE"? Have you tried to boot the VM into rescue environment (systemrescuecd, etc.), what does it look like (separated /boot or combined with /, what version of a bootloader is there — I don't remember whether RHEL5 uses grub1 or grub2, and so on)?

Hi Nikita Kipriyanox. I followed the guide: 1. Export XVA file from XenServer -> 2. copy xva file to promox server -> 3. create new VM on promox without harddisk -> 4. import xva to new VM on promox ( https://www.vinchin.com/vm-migration/proxmox-import-xva.html )
